# clear all from Simulink S-function

Tags: simulink, s-function

I am trying to call clear all from a simulink Level 1 S-function. I've take a look over  `doc mexCallMATLAB` but I do not know how to use it. I've wanted to clear the work space after my function is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you're writing a level-1 S-Function?  If you are, then you shouldn't.  These days both m-code and c-code S-Functions should all be written as level-2.

You haven't specifically indicated whether you are writing in m-code or c-code, but since you've mentioned `mexCallMATLAB` it's assumed that you are using c-code, in which case you should use

```
mexEvalString("clear('all');");
```

If you're using m-code, then just use

```
evalin('base','clear all');
```